# how to execute a process while system starting using c# service

Tags: windows, service, c#, windows-services

I have a c# service i need to execute a particular process while device is starting. How can i do this using c#. I don't know how to detect windows is starting.

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new Process();
                            proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
                            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = details["arguments"];
                            proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";      
                            proc.Start();
                            proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You want your service to start on Windows startup, or you want your service to start another process on startup? I'm slightly confused.

Comment: @Broots Waymb i need service to start another process on startup

Comment: Do you know how to have windows start your process on startup? After configuring that, getting this code to run when your service starts should be pretty darn easy.

Comment: @Broots Waymb while restarting device service onstart code is running. But in case of shutdown and power on service on start code is not running

Comment: Ah ok, you might want to reformulate your question so that it's more about the fact that `OnStart` isn't being called. The fact that you're trying to execute another process is more of a distraction to the actual issue.

Comment: So is your service just not being started when you do a shutdown/power on? How do you have this configured in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the service to Automatic in the Services window and on start execute your code or start a timer to launch shortly after.

Comment: while restarting device onstrt code is running. but after shutdown and power on onstart code is not executing

Answer (score 1):

One way to detect windows starting (or just started) is to use [System.Envinroment.TickCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Environment_TickCount) which returns the number of milliseconds since the system started.
You need to set a variable to indicate that you have read and acted on this, as after roughly a month it rolls over to zero again as it runs out of space to store such a big number. (EDIT - as pointed out, it is signed and goes negative)

```
int result = Environment.TickCount
```

if result is less than say 300,000 then windows has restarted in the last 5 minutes. Obviously you need to plan that not all computers reboot quickly.

**EDIT**
Now we know issue is that onStart isn't being called...based on comment above...
1) OP, are you sure that the device is actually shutting down, not just sleeping/hibernating
2) Have you checked windows event logs to prove that service did actually stop and start?

Comment: How does this answer the question? If OP needs to do something at startup, knowing the milliseconds since startup doesn't help at all.

Comment: He says " I don't know how to detect windows is starting.". Clearly, he can get his service to start at startup which is half the battle, but it might also be manually restarted any time. Checking TickCount in combination with service starting verifies windows has recently restarted.

Comment: OP doesn't want to do something X milliseconds/minutes/etc after startup. They want to know how to do something immediately, so I don't see the benefit here. Also, `TickCount` is signed, so it's going to cycle back to `Int32.Minvalue`, not zero.

Comment: I didn't word it well. I assumed he was setting his service to autostart, so he will get the earliest chance possible to examine TickCount and verify that windows has just started. I wasn't intending to suggest he waits. Point taken about min value. I thought he was saying "How do I know if my service has started because windows started or because someone has manually started it".

Comment: Based on his last comment, it looks as though his issue is that the device is sleeping / hibernating rather than doing a full power down and reboot. I can't comment on that one though as I don't have 15 rep yet.

Comment: Another issue this will have is that obviously your variables aren't persisted. So if the service gets restarted multiple times within the 300,000ms (or whatever interval), the service won't know that it has already acted for startup.

Comment: Thanks, been a while since I needed to write a service and I forgot that detail.  This whole thing is now red herring as the OP's question didn't actually ask what he wanted to know.